# How to execute the feature file one by one mentioned order in feature tag of testng runner class

Tags: cucumber, test-runner

How to execute the feature file one by one in a mentioned order of feature tag in testng runner class

ex:

@cucumberOptions(
tag="src/feature3.feature,
src/feature1.feature"
)

Need to execute the feature3 first after that feature1 need to be executed.

Comment: Switch the names of the feature files. I think if the files are in same folder they are picked in alphabetic order. Try it maybe it works. Though never a good idea to fix orders of features or tests

Comment: can we use getfeatures() method to get the list of features mentioned in glue tag of test runner class

Comment: which class exposes this method? I dont think cucumber exposes its inner workings. To get access to features etc u need to create a custom class that implements Formatter interface. The framework will then call the appropriate methods of this class based on the current events. Though i am not sure it will help u much.